# Connecting Laney MINI amp with iPhones (Without headphone jack)

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, electric-bass-guitar

I recently purchased [Laney MINI ST Amp](https://www.laney.co.uk/products/mini-mini-st-lion-battery-powered-combo) which has a interesting feature called LSI interface which allows user to connect their laney guitar amplifer to an IOS app called [tonebridge](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tonebridge-guitar-effects/id1117291846) which can allow laney amp to generate wide range of tones and FX using virtual pedals in the app. For this they provide an cable which is male-male 3.5mm cable with [4 ring jack](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_pin/TRRS-Audio-Jack-Pinout.png) (Like headphone cable pin). whose one end connect to amp and other to mobile phone's headphone jack.

**THE PROBLEM**

I own an iPhone 7 which do not have a headphone jack. My question is will a [lightning to 3.5mm adapter](https://www.mytrendyphone.eu/images2/Apple-MMX62ZM-A-Lightning-to-3.5mm-Adapter-12092016-01-p.jpg) will fix my issue? Because app is designed to pick analog input from a headphone jack and not from USB port. So will it support that adapter?

I believe that this LSI interface is very similar to iRig adapters which also does the same thing and people in blogs say that it works with the lightning to 3.5mm adapters so can I assume same analogy for my case as well?

Comment: Have you asked Laney? Have you asked Apple? Have you considered Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time has passed since you posted this issue so I assume that you have tested the Mini Laney. The answer you're looking for is in Laney's youtube video. Basically you connect the lightning adapter to the 3.5mm jack and it works fine!

As we know that it works with iOS devices (iPhone, iPad), does it also work with macOS (Macbook)? I know that connecting Mini Laney to an iPhone is very convenient and mobile solution but from time to time I'd like to use a bigger screen to play around with Tonebridge sounds. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have a Laney amp, but I do have an (I think) Griffin iPhone/guitar cable that uses the same TRRS connector to send the guitar signal down to the iPhone, where some app (in my case AmpliTube) processed the signal and sends it back on the headphone return. It works great (still) on my old iPad 2.

It works with my iPhone 11 & Apple headphone adaptor for very low values of work - low volume, weird noises, clicks, etc. It’s not really usable. This doesn’t mean that the Laney Mini amp will necessarily be like this, but I wouldn’t have high expectations.

Comment: I've forgotten to update this thread. I've already gotten my answer. It works fine with the original adapter cable .. other duplicate cables never worked for me. It works without any noise but the latency sucks sometimes. although it varies device to device widely

Comment: The problem with Griffin and similar cables is that they're basically guitar preamps that work on electret microphone bias voltage and made with extremely small budget. You can't make a good preamp under those constraints.